# PDF First Three Pages Extractor using Python

Tags: python, pypdf

So I tried writing a code where when I insert the address of a pdf file into my code below,It extracts only the first 3 pages of the pdf and save it as(nameofthepdf_subset.pdf).
But now I want to this to happen to every Pdf in the folder, How do I make it happen?

This my code which I got from a YouTube channel:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

pdf_file_path = r"C:\Users\91885\OneDrive\Desktop\Python 3 Pages\IELTS.pdf"
file_base_name = pdf_file_path.replace('.pdf', '')

pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file_path)

pages = [0, 1, 2] # page 1,2,3
pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()

for page_num in pages:
    pdfWriter.addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num))

with open('{0}_subset.pdf'.format(file_base_name), 'wb') as f:
    pdfWriter.write(f)
    f.close()
```

This code works fine but only for a single a pdf, how do I insert my folder address in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to save the first 3 pages in a different pdf for all pdfs in the given folder

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import os

for file in os.listdir("path_to_foler"):

    file_base_name = file

    pdf = PdfFileReader(f'path_to_foler/{file}')

    pages = [0, 1, 2]  # page 1,2,3
    pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()

    for page_num in pages:
        pdfWriter.addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num))

    with open(f'{file_base_name}_subset.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        pdfWriter.write(f)
```

One Tip when you a `with open("file","mode") as file:`you don't need to close the file the with statement closes the datastream automatically when the code inside has finished